# loadScript returns undefined

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 for creating a private ethereum blockchain using geth. I am required to load the "Simple.abi" script present inside home/contract. But when I give the file-path in the loadScript it returns undefined even though my path is correct with respect to the home. Can anyone tell me their quick thoughts about what the issue is??

[image]

Comment: What is the content of "Simple.abi"? What is the output you were expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Just proceed with

```
>loadScript("Simple.bin")
>miner.start(1)
(wait for miner, will mine 1 block)
>simple.function(inputs)
```

It will still work, as documented in https://gus-tavo-guim.medium.com/deploying-a-smart-contract-the-hard-way-8aae778d4f2a.

What I get is

```
>loadScript("Simple.abi")
undefined
>loadScript("Simple.bin")
undefined
>miner.start(1)
null
(wait for miner, will mine 1 block)
>simple.multiply.call(5,10)
50
```